# Create a variable that is 0 for the first non-NA of a different variable, then counts up/down from 0 for other values *grouped by* a third variable

Tags: r, conditional-statements, tidyr, dplyr

I have the following df:

```
df <- tibble(country = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "Mex", "Mex"),
         year = c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2000, 2001),
         score = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 426, NA, NA, 430, NA, 450, NA))
```

What I'd like to do: create a new variable `years_from_implementation` that is **0** the first year that a country has a non-NA value for `score` and represents the number of years *from* 0 for all other values.

In other words, hard coding it, I'd like it to return the following df:

```
df <- tibble(country = c("US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "US", "Mex", "Mex"),
         year = c(1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2000, 2001),
         score = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 426, NA, NA, 430, NA, 450, NA),
         years_from_implementation = c(-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,0,1))
```

This, all done when grouping by `country`.

I tried to couple `df <- mutate(df, before_after = case_when(!is.na(score) ~ 0))` with the `fill` command, but couldn't get any movement.

Tidyverse solutions would be much preferred, but truly any help will be immensely appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` option

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    mutate(years_from_implementation = 1:n() - which(score == first(score[!is.na(score)]))) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 11 x 4
#   country  year score years_from_implementation
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>                     <int>
# 1 US       1999    NA                        -4
# 2 US       2000    NA                        -3
# 3 US       2001    NA                        -2
# 4 US       2002    NA                        -1
# 5 US       2003   426                         0
# 6 US       2004    NA                         1
# 7 US       2005    NA                         2
# 8 US       2006   430                         3
# 9 US       2007    NA                         4
#10 Mex      2000   450                         0
#11 Mex      2001    NA                         1
```

Comment: This is PHENOMENAL. So, so good; accomplishes exactly what I need and using logic that's totally readable. Thanks, Maurits!

Comment: You're very welcome @wscampbell; glad it was helpful.

Comment: Nice answer! Should be able to reduce this to `df %>%
  group_by(country) %>%
  mutate(years_from_implementation = 1:n() - which.max(!is.na(score)))
`

Comment: That's neat @RonakShah; I wasn't sure at first why `which.max` worked, so had to run your code step-by-step to realise that `which.max` breaks ties by reporting the first occurrence. Clever.

Comment: This Maurits-@RonakShah hybrid solution seems best: 

`score_df <- score_df %>%
    arrange(country, year) %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    mutate(years_from_imp = 1:n() - which.max(!is.na(score))) %>%
    ungroup()`

Which should I edit/count as the final solution?!

Comment: @wscampbell that decision is yours but if I were you I would have selected Maurits' answer since it doesn't create any additional variable + it is more smarter approach than mine.

Answer (score 1):

We can find out the row-index where the first non-NA `score` appears and then create a sequence from `1 - index` to `n() - index` for every group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(country) %>%
   mutate(index = which.max(!is.na(score)), 
          years_from_implementation = (1 - index[1]):(n() - index[1])) %>%
   select(-index)

# country  year score years_from_implementation
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>                     <int>
# 1 US       1999    NA                        -4
# 2 US       2000    NA                        -3
# 3 US       2001    NA                        -2
# 4 US       2002    NA                        -1
# 5 US       2003   426                         0
# 6 US       2004    NA                         1
# 7 US       2005    NA                         2
# 8 US       2006   430                         3
# 9 US       2007    NA                         4
#10 Mex      2000   450                         0
#11 Mex      2001    NA                         1
```